# Logstash with elasticsearch input and output keep looping results

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I would like to reindex and filter my log again. What I get the information from Internet is using the logstash to filter the data again.
I tried and it can really split my data into different fields, however, the data keeps looping. That is, I have 100,000 logs but after filtering and output to elasticsearch, I found that more than 100,000 logs are output into elasticsearch and the logs are duplicated. Does anyone have idea on that?

Moreover, I receive below log when running logstash, although it said that error phasing JSON, I found that the log can still be filtered. Why would be like that?
Thank you!

**Here is my logstash config:**

```
input {

elasticsearch {

      hosts => "10.0.132.56"
      index => "logstash-2018.01.04"
      }
}

filter{
     grok {
            match => {"message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:logdate} %{GREEDYDATA:vmname}  %{GREEDYDATA:message}"}
     overwrite => [ "message" ]
     }
}

filter {
       json {
         source => "scrmsg"
       }
}


output {
     elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["10.0.132.64:9200"]
        manage_template => false
        index => "logstash-2018.01.04-1"
     }
}
```

**Here is the error log:**

```
[2018-01-11T15:15:32,010][WARN ][logstash.filters.json    ] Error parsing json {:source=>"scrmsg", :raw=>"Trident/5.0)\",\"geoip_country\":\"US\",\"allowed\":\"1\",\"threat_score\":\"268435456\",\"legacy_unique_id\":\"\",\"cache_status\":\"-\",\"informed_id\":\"\",\"primitive_id\":\"2BC2D8AD-7AD0-3CAD-9453-B0335F409701\",\"valid_ajax\":\"0\",\"orgin_response_time\":\"0.081\",\"request_id\":\"cd2ae0a8-0921-48b6-b03f-15c71a55100b\",\"bytes_returned_origin\":\"83\",\"server_ip\":\"10.0.10.16\",\"origin_status_code\":\"\",\"calculated_pages_per_min\":\"1\",\"calculated_pages_per_session\":\"1\",\"calculated_session_length\":\"0\",\"k_s\":\"\",\"origin_address\":\"10.0.10.16:443\",\"request_protocol\":\"https\",\"server_serial\":\"5c3eb4ad-3799-4bd8-abb2-42edecd54b99\",\"nginx_worker_process\":\"19474\",\"origin_content_type\":\"application/json;charset=UTF-8\",\"lb_request_time\":\"\",\"SID\":\"\",\"geoip_org\":\"Drake Holdings LLC\",\"accept\":\"*/*\",\"accept_encoding\":\"gzip, deflate\",\"accept_language\":\"\",\"connection\":\"Keep-Alive\",\"http_request_length\":\"418\",\"real_ip_header_value\":\"204.79.180.18\",\"http_host\":\"www.honeyworkshop.com\",\"machine_learning_score\":\"\",\"HSIG\":\"ALE_UHCF\",\"ZID\":\"\",\"ZUID\":\"\",\"datacenter_id\":\"363\",\"new_platform_domain_id\":\"3063fc0b-5b48-4413-9bc7-600039caf64c\",\"whitelist_score\":\"0\",\"billable\":\"1\",\"distil_action\":\"@proxy\",\"js_additional_threats\":\"\",\"js_kv_additional_threats\":\"\",\"re_field_1\":\"\",\"re_field_2\":\"\",\"re_field_3\":\"\",\"http_accept_charset\":\"\",\"sdk_token_id\":\"\",\"sdk_application_instance_id\":\"\",\"per_path_calculated_pages_per_minute\":\"1\",\"per_path_calculated_pages_per_session\":\"1\",\"path_security_type\":\"api\",\"identification_provider\":\"web\",\"identifier_record_pointer\":\"\",\"identifier_record_value\":\"\",\"path_rule_scope_id\":\"\",\"experiment_id\":\"0\",\"experiment_score\":\"\",\"experiment_group_id\":\"\",\"experiment_auxiliary_string\":\"\",\"type\":\"distil\"}\n", :exception=>#<LogStash::Json::ParserError: Unrecognized token 'Trident': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source: (byte[])"Trident/5.0)","geoip_country":"US","allowed":"1","threat_score":"268435456","legacy_unique_id":"","cache_status":"-","informed_id":"","primitive_id":"2BC2D8AD-7AD0-3CAD-9453-B0335F409701","valid_ajax":"0","orgin_response_time":"0.081","request_id":"cd2ae0a8-0921-48b6-b03f-15c71a55100b","bytes_returned_origin":"83","server_ip":"10.0.10.16","origin_status_code":"","calculated_pages_per_min":"1","calculated_pages_per_session":"1","calculated_session_length":"0","k_s":"","origin_address":"10.0.10"[truncated 1180 bytes]; line: 1, column: 9]>}
```

Comment: when you try and get the results, how do you request the data? if its through kibana you might see duplicates because you see both indexes. pick one record, filter on it so you see that and its duplicate and compare the _index field.
the error log has no relevance, it just means that the parser left the data in its original form, it didn't make it into a JSON object

Comment: Yes, I found them on kibana. However, the index was different because I renamed the index to "logstash-2018.01.04-1" and also the data also send to another host "10.0.132.64:9200". If I don't stop the logstash service, it will get into infinite loop until the elasticsearch disk space is full.

Comment: i have seen the different result index, im curious that when you search in kibana, do you use "logstash-*" as search pattern, and if you do and compare one record to its duplicate, are the indexes the same, or is it the original and the transformed, or is it two transformed?

Comment: I have two kibana, when I search, i use the index "logstash-2018.01.04" in one kibana, and use the index "logstash-2018.01.04-1" in another kibana. I set the search time is from 4th Jan 2018 00:00:00.000 to 4th Jan 2018 23:59:59.999. And I found that the total number for index "logstash-2018.01.04" is 149810 hits while index "logstash-2018.01.04-1" is 163250 hits. And if I do not stop the logstash service, the hits number of index "logstash-2018.01.04-1" keeps increasing.

Comment: anyone can help?

Comment: I took your configuration and since I didn't have your records in my index (the very same index with 21 records) I removed the filter options. Also I changed the server IP address but other than that I changed nothing. I ran the configuration as a task from the command line, not as a service (sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f <config path>) and it finished in about 5 seconds. I got the new index on my server with 21 records.

Comment: Which version of ELK are you using?

Comment: I am using ELK 6.1.0. I will try to run as a task and see the result, as i run (systemctl start logstash.service) before.

Comment: I have tried to use this command (sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f <config path>) rather than service. I found that the origin record is 149810 but after transfer to new elasticsearch, it only has 149000 record. Do you have any idea? I removed all filters and just used input and output to try.

Comment: Did you search by index or by date? During my early export-import tasks I checked the import result by date but the logstash index creation doesnt use local time so if you're not in 0 offset timezone you should check the count by index and not by timestamp. Is this possibly the solution?

Comment: I searched by index. So it should not affect by the date. Also, this situation is randomly happened. I have tried to reindex another index, it works once, but when I tried again later on, it loops again.

Comment: If your goal is to reindex your records I would offer elasticdump. https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump This is what I use to import-export between servers and I had no problem with it before. I know this is not an answer to the original (logstash) question, but I'm out of ideas in that topic. Maybe this helps. (note: I export-import into and from files since I have to move them between servers, no experience with server-server dumping)

Comment: Thanks @MrSimple. But I need to use the json filter to reindex origin data. Seems that elasticdump can only input and output data but cannot filter the data again.

Comment: You could also try and use file input on logstash with patterns and then write the filter. I know I'm grasping and it's kind of a hack but if it works...